# Unable to export 2 Higher Order Components from one JS file in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have 2 Components in a file and I am trying to supercharge them and export them as HOCs.

```
export default withStyles(styles)(Component1);

export withStyles(styles)(Component2);
```

But, I am getting error on second export. However, if I change it to:

```
export Component2OtherWay = withStyles(styles)(Component2);
```

Then, it is working fine. Could anyone explain this to me?

Cheers!

Comment: how are you importing them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the second export is a named export you need to give it a name which is why you are getting the error.

A file can have **only one default export** and you need to not give a name to the component exported as default but for a named export you need to give a name which is what the second syntax does

```
export const Component2OtherWay  = withStyles(styles)(Component2);
```

Also a named export can be imported like

```
import { Component2OtherWay } from 'path/to/Component';
```

Answer (score 1):

The `default` keyword has nothing to do with multiple exports. It's just a name. It’s exported under `default` name.

So you need another name to export next component.